# How to use a File object as css image source?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a reference to a javascript File object (image) which was provided by the user from a "open file dialog". How do I load this image file into a css background-image without having to read all data into a base64-string first?

The examples I have found use a FileReader to read the data and then load that into the css-tag but this seems like a bit of ineffective use of memory. Since I have the File-reference it would be nice if I could pass that into the css-tag somehow instead and let the image be streamed into memory instead. The url()-wrapper for "background-image" supports local filenames but for security reasons the full path of the File is not available to my script so I can't use that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how about you use a [blob URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url) to reference your image in CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have your File object in a variable called `file`.

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
yourElement.style.background = `url(${url})`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL